# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string, using c# in order to check a table in SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am beginner in C# and I am developing an import system. In the code below I am trying to check if the date in the imported Excel file corresponds to the first or the second half year. Before the actual import, all registrations need to be deleted. The code works fine but when I am executing the delete command I get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Please help!

P.S.: I have read the other posts about this error but I couldn't identify similarities with my code.

Thank you!

```
string input = (string)table.Rows[2][27];
string neededDate = input.Substring(29);
string getmonth = input.Substring(32, 2);
string getyear = input.Substring(35, 4);

if (int.Parse(getmonth) <= 6 && int.Parse(getyear) == DateTime.Now.Year)
{
    var date1 = DateTime.Today;
    var year = date1.Year;

    DateTime start1 = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
    DateTime end1 = new DateTime(year, 6, 30);

    db.ExecuteCommand("Delete from Table where Date between '" + start1 + "' AND '" + end1 +"'");                  
}
else if (int.Parse(getmonth) > 6 && int.Parse(getyear) == DateTime.Now.Year)
{
    var date2 = DateTime.Today;
    var year = date2.Year;

    DateTime  start2 = new DateTime(year, 7, 1);
    DateTime  end2 = new DateTime(year, 12, 31);

    db.ExecuteCommand("Delete from Table where Date  between '" + start2 + "' AND '" + end2 + "'");                     
}
else
{
    Console.Write("");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its probably due to a wrong date format used.
I believe that using `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` on the dates will work for you.

```
db.ExecuteCommand("Delete from Table where Date between '" + start1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                   + "' AND '" +  end1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") +"'");
```

But, using these kind of queries is considered bad-practice and can lead to sql-injection (although not in your specific case because the data is not coming from the users).

You should start using parameterized queries instead:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

var command = con.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "Delete from Table where Date between @start AND @end";
command.Parameters.Add("@start", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = start1;
command.Parameters.Add("@end", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = end1;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Hello Ofir. Thank you for your answer! I could fix the error by using ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") and the code work fine now. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Glad it worked for you, I really recommend you to have a go with the parameterized queries

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues and observations for you.

Why are you casting the value (row 2, column 27) to a string? Is it not a DateTime value already? If not, it probably should. This would remove the need for you to manually parse the data. By manually parsing the data, you are not taking into account different DateTime formats. 
e.g.

```
DateTime input = DateTime.Parse(table.Rows[2][27].ToString());
```

You can check for null values using:

```
table.Rows[2].IsNull(27);
```

Is column 27 the [Date] column you reference in your delete statement? If it's a string, then you'll have to cast the column and the values to DateTime types to use the BETWEEN syntax.

When dealing with dates, try specify the correct format
SQL Server and .Net have different date formats by default.

You should also use parameterized SQL, not string concatenation as it leaves you potentially open to sql injection.

```
DELETE FROM [Table] WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Comment: Hello Jonny. Thank you for your answer! It is not a DateTime format the value (row 2, column 27). The value of teh column is something like: "Date from: 01.01.2017 to 31.07.2017" and I only need to use the second date, that is why I am using substring.

Comment: The column [Date] from my delete statement is the column from the table in the Sql server database that I am using as a condition to delete records. Column [27] is from the excel file that I would ike to import.

Comment: Hi Michelle, no problem. I would still suggest converting it to a DateTime if you know the format e.g. DateTime.Parse("31.07.2017", "dd.MM.yyyy"). Switching to parameterized SQL will also likely fix any DateTime formatting issues.

Comment: And I have also tryied parameterized SQL but the same.

Comment: I am still workig in to trying to convert  to DateTime. The only change I have made is adding ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") to my start and end dates. And works just fine. But maybe I can make my code look a bit nicer :)